# How to identify if a git commit skipped pre-hook checks or not?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

We have set of predefined pre-hooks which checks for code validation and runs commit message enforcers and some-other things, but people tend to skip this validations by running `git commit -n`.

Is there way to identify those commits which skipped pre-hooks ? Or can we add some metadata to each commit with pre-hooks passed or pre-hooks failed ?

Thanks,

Comment: "*Is there way to identify those commits which skipped pre-hooks ?*" No. "*Or can we add some metadata…*" Then your teammates will add such metadata manually. There is nothing you can do at the user's hosts. The right solution is to repeat the checks at the server-side in `pre-receive` or `update` hooks.

Comment: This is probably a ”you’re using the wrong tool for the job” problem, define gitlab ci jobs to enforce whatever requirements you have on MRs

Comment: The [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks) is very clear that there are many ways to bypass client-side hooks, and server-side hooks or CI jobs are the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this would be using a [server side hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html) or in a CI job.

If you use the tool [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/), you can use [this CI job template](https://gitlab.com/yesolutions/gitlab-ci-templates/-/blob/main/templates/pre-commit-autofix.yaml) to automatically check pre-commit hooks and, optionally, automatically apply automatic fixes to the source branch from the CI job.

For GitHub.com users, there's also [pre-commit.ci](https://pre-commit.ci/).